# Switch laptop HDD into SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Has anyone tried to switch Fujitsu LH700 (laptop) HDD into a SSD (with success or fail).

I heard that some laptops(motherboard) are made so that it can only read registered HDD. Restricting the user to interfere with the original parts.

As well, if I am switching into a "smaller" SSD, what do I need to be careful of?

Thank you very much for all the advises.

*if more information is required, please ask and I will add them.

Comment: For the actual cloning operation, in my experience, software based cloners from HD to SSD have yielded unbootable hd's. Make sure to take a look at hardware based cloners as well, got one for $30 on amazon and it works wonders.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this particular machine, but I have also *never* come across a consumer laptop that has had this restriction (Not to say it couldn't exist, I can't say that with absolute certainty, but I have never seen it happen).

Looking on Crucial's website, their SSD recommendation tool lists plenty of compatible drives [here](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Fujitsu/lifebook-lh700). That is not to say you can only use Crucial of course, however they are claiming them to be compatible and not limited to certain drives, and if it didn't work you'd have evidence of their recommendation.

Depending on how you plan to migrate to the SSD could be affected by the size of the drive. If you're happy doing a clean installation from scratch, you'll have no problems. Just be aware that if you plan to clone the HDD to the SSD, your software may need to take into account shrinking the partition. Most software will handle this without too much more than just a confirmation box though.

Do also consider if the drive will actually be big enough. A lot of people fall into the trap of getting an SSD big enough for the operating system, forgetting they use it day to day also. I'd suggest a *minimum* of a 128GB drive if you're a ***very*** light user, or have an external drive to store most of your data on (I have a 128GB boot SSD, with a 750GB storage HDD.) Otherwise, even 256GB can get used up pretty quickly depending on what you're installing and doing with the machine.

Comment: thanks for the well explained comment. Technology advances faster than I learn and update the news now, so I was uncertain. By the way, do you have any recommended software for clone and shrink the partition?

When you say "clone", does it mean that I don't even need a CD for it? As I have no experience in cloning a HDD with OS inside onto another HDD or SSD.